# Singular distribution F such that convolution F and F is an absolutely continuous distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

F is a singular distribution function concentrated on the positive half-line. Is it possible that 2-fold convolution F*F is an absolutely continuous distribution function? Please, give me an example.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvotes here?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

Such an example, first given by Wiener and Wintner (Fourier--Stieltjes transforms and singular infinite convolutions, Amer. J. Math., vol. 60 (1938), 513-522), is nontrivial.

For instance, no convolution power of the Cantor distribution is absolutely continuous. Indeed, for the characteristic function $f$ of the Cantor distribution we have
$$|f(t)|=\prod_{k=0}^\infty|\cos(3^{-k}t)|$$
for real $t$ and hence $|f(3^m\pi)|=|f(\pi)|>0$ for natural $m$, so that $f(t)\not\to0$ as $t\to\infty$ (whereas, by the Riemann--Lebesgue lemma, we would have to have $f(t)\to0$ as $t\to\infty$ if any convolution power of the Cantor distribution were absolutely continuous).

For a more general result, with a singular distribution $\nu$ on any given locally compact nondiscrete group such that $\nu*\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Haar measure, see e.g. [this paper](https://www.ams.org/proc/1999-127-10/S0002-9939-99-04827-3/S0002-9939-99-04827-3.pdf) by Bisbas, who writes this in the beginning of the paper:

> In 1938, Wiener and Wintner [9], [3], p.209, proved that there exists a singular
> probability measure $\mu$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ such that $\mu*\mu$ is absolutely continuous.

Of course, if you insist on a distribution on the positive half-line, you just need to shift that $\mu$ to the right by $\pi$.